# How to write insert query for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, foreign-key-relationship

How to write insert query for stored procedure.

I have 2 tables `user` and `orders`.

When I execute this query its running perfectly.

eg : -

```
insert into Orders
values((select Users.Uid from Users where Users.Uname = 'asim'), 15)
```

but when I'm trying to convert same into stored procedure I am getting an error.

```
create proc insert_Orders_sp
    @Uname
as
    insert into Orders(Uid, Quantity)
    values((select Users.Uid from Users where Users.Uname = @Uname), 15)
```

I couldn't understand where I made the mistake.

Please help me out..[orders table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTxao.jpg)

Comment: Well, ***what error*** exactly are you getting? We can't read your screen, nor your mind - you'll  **have to TELL US!**

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure insert_Orders_sp, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'begin'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure insert_Orders_sp, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@Uname".

Comment: You have some other stuff on your screen besides what you show.   There is no "BEGIN" in the script you posted.

Comment: i want to convert :'' insert into Orders
values((select Users.Uid from Users where Users.Uname='asim'),15) '' into stored procedure, where i want to get the user id by selecting the user name. & I don't know how to do that.

Comment: generally it is working fine but it is not working while am trying to convert it into stored procedure.

Comment: Please help me out...

Comment: You haven't posted all of your code.  We can only help you if you post all of your code. Did you see the comment about that? Why wouldn't you respond to that if you want a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

```
create proc insert_Orders_sp
    @Uname  varchar(20)
as
    insert into Orders(Uid, Quantity)
    values((select Users.Uid from Users where Users.Uname = @Uname), 15)
```

But you say you're getting syntax errors.  Are you trying to write this as part of a script that also does other things?  A `create proc` statement needs to be the first statement in a batch.

To make it the first statement in a batch but do other things as well, you can do this:

```
if exists (select name from sys.objects where name = 'insert_Orders_sp')
begin
    drop proc insert_Orders_sp
end
go   -- Separates the batch

create proc insert_Orders_sp
    @Uname  varchar(20)
as
    insert into Orders(Uid, Quantity)
    values((select Users.Uid from Users where Users.Uname = @Uname), 15)

go
```

You can't wrap a procedure creation script in an `IF .. BEGIN .. END` statement because of the requirement that the `create procedure` be the first statement in the batch.  (There are workarounds, but they are a bit more complex.)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the Datatype for the SP Parameter

```
create proc insert_Orders_sp
    @Uname varchar(10) -- Missing Datatype
as
    insert into Orders(Uid, Quantity)
    values((select Users.Uid from Users where Users.Uname = @Uname), 15)
```

Your insert stmt that you are running separately will always work because it does not use a variable. So the SP and the ins stmt are not comparable.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @objectNotFound, you have missed Data Type while declaring parameter of SP.

Answer (score 0):

In stored procedure if you declare parameter then its mandatory to declare its datatype like in your case you forgot to declare datatype:-

```
CREATE proc insert_Orders_sp @Uname varchar(10) -- Missing Datatype here in brackets 10 is size of datatype    
AS INSERT INTO Orders(UID, Quantity) VALUES(
        (SELECT Users.Uid
         FROM Users
         WHERE Users.Uname = @Uname), 15)
```